# Django website unabale to register new users

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am following [Antoinio Mele's -Django by example](https://learning.oreilly.com/library/view/django-3-by/9781838981952/Text/Chapter_4.xhtml)  to build a Social Website but everythime I try to register a new user through the register.html template all I get is a blank form ,neither does the webiste create a new user.

I've followed everything that's said in the tutorial.

My views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
#from .forms import LoginForm,UserRegistrationForm
from .forms import LoginForm,UserRegistrationForm 
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

def user_login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            user = authenticate(request,username=cd['username'],
                                        password=cd['password'])
            if user is not None:
                if user.is_active:
                    login(request,user)
                    return HttpResponse('Authenticated successfully')
                else:
                    return HttpResponse('Disabled account')
            else:
                return HttpResponse('Invalid login')
    else:
        form = LoginForm()
    return render(request,'account/login.html',{'form':form})

@login_required
def dashboard(request):
    return render(request,
                  'account/dashboard.html',
                  {'section':'dashboard'})
    
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if user_form.is_valid():
            # Create a new user object but avoid saving it yet
            #new_user = user_form.save(commit=False)
            new_user = user_form.save()
            # Set the chosen password
            new_user.set_password(
                user_form.cleaned_data['password'])
            # Save the User object
            new_user.save()
            # Create the user profile
           # Profile.objects.create(user=new_user)
            return render(request,
                          'account/register_done.html',
                          {'new_user': new_user})
    else:
        user_form = UserRegistrationForm()
    return render(request,
                  'account/register.html',
                  {'user_form': user_form})
```

My urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from . import views
urlpatterns=[
   #path('login/',views.user_login,name='login'),
   path('login/',auth_views.LoginView.as_view(),name='login'),
   path('logout/',auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(),name='logout'),
   path('',views.dashboard,name='dashboard'),
   path('register/',views.register,name='register'),
]
```

my register.html

```
{% extends 'account/base.html' %}
{% block title %}
   Create an account
{% endblock title %}
{% block content %}
    <h1>Create an account</h1>  
     
    <p class=" class_name">
     Please,sign up using the following form:
    </p>
     
   <form mehtod='post'> 
     {{ user_form.as_p }}
     {% csrf_token %}  <!--cross site request frogery-->
      
     <p><input type="submit" value="Create my account"></p>
      
   </form>
{% endblock content %}
```

my forms.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django import forms
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField()
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

class UserRegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(label='Password',
                               widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Repeat password',
                                widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'email')

    def clean_password2(self):
        cd = self.cleaned_data
        if cd['password'] != cd['password2']:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Passwords don\'t match.')
        return cd['password2']
```

Any little assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the code below, you can print form data to trace its status

```
# Create a new user object but avoid saving it yet
            # create new instance of user
            new_user = user_form.save(commit=False)

            # Set the chosen password
            new_user.password = user_form.cleaned_data['password'])

            # Save the User object
            new_user.save()
```

Comment: That still does not have any effect.

Comment: I can see that your issue was typo !! so is everything is fine now?

Comment: Yeah, now the code is functioning properly. Thank you for willingness.

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in your html, `<form mehtod='post'>` should be `<form method='post'>` so the form is being sent as a GET request instead.

Comment: What are you talking about ? I already have ```<form method='post'> ``` in my template.

Comment: You spelled it wrong, you spelled mehtod, it should be method!

Comment: That worked like a charm for me !!! . YOU ARE AN ANGEL IN DISGUISE .

Comment: You're welcome!  Glad i could help.